# Move object in a straight line to another point

Tags: c#, winforms

I am struggling to get this right. 
What I want to do is to move a panel(10px by 10px) to another panel which is the same size.

I want to see how it moves to the other panel... and I achieved this using a timer.

My code works, but I do have a problem I cannot get past...

Most of the time the panel that is moving, first reaches the x or y coordinate and then move in a horizontal or vertical line to the other panel.

This looks OK when moving very fast... but when moving slowly I can see that it looks very wrong.

This is just a small paint job i have created to show you what i have in mind:
[image]

I want point B to move to point A in a straight line.

CODE:

```
        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            smallX = pnlTo.Location.X;
            smallY = pnlTo.Location.Y;
            largeX = pnlFrom.Location.X;
            largeY = pnlFrom.Location.Y;

            //Should we find the ratio??

            // ####### X #######
            if (largeX != smallX)
            {
                int xRatio;
                if (largeX > smallX)
                {
                    //If 'large' is to the right.
                    //Find ratio.
                    xRatio = largeX / smallX;
                    pnlFrom.Left -= xRatio;
                }
                else
                {
                    //If 'large' is to the left.
                    //Find ratio.
                    xRatio = smallX / largeX;
                    pnlFrom.Left += xRatio;
                }
            }

            // ####### Y #######
            if (largeY != smallY)
            {
                int yRatio;
                if (largeY > smallY)
                {
                    //If 'large' is to the bottom.
                    yRatio = largeY / smallY;
                    pnlFrom.Top -= yRatio;

                    //pnlFrom.Top -= pixelsToMove;
                }
                else
                {
                    //If 'large' is to the top.
                    yRatio = smallY / largeY;
                    pnlFrom.Top += yRatio;

                    //pnlFrom.Top += pixelsToMove;

                }
            }

            lblLargeX.Text = pnlFrom.Location.X.ToString();
            lblLargeY.Text = pnlFrom.Location.Y.ToString();

            if (largeX == smallX && largeY == smallY)
            {
                timer.Stop();
            }
        }
```

I know I am very wrong with how to achieve this... but can someone please help me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea how your algorithm should work and what mistakes are (either in logic or in implementation), but moving from `(x1;y1)` to `(x2;y2)` is simple:

```
int steps = 10; // how many steps animation/timer will have
int x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * step / steps;
int y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * step / steps;
```

Notes:

- `(x,y)` is coords at given step
- `step` is current step in the range: from 1 to `steps`
- multiply first, then divide!
- you have to store initial/final position for this to work (unlike classical `delta` algorithm, for which you must use `float`/`double` and only store `delta` and `steps`);

Comment: Slowdown timer or decrease number of steps (with same timer frequency). For smooth animation you need certain framerate though, so increasing number of steps, while having 10 Hz (or faster) timer is preferable, than reducing to 1 Hz timer.

Answer (score 0):

You might find a smoother way is to check the difference in X and Y before beginning, then using that divided by how many steps you want to make as a 'velocity'. So, if you want to move in 10 ticks, calculate LargeY and SmallY, then divide that by ticks and set a class level variable to that amount. Each tick increment by that amount.